# Why does it always display an error message?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello all I study with javascript, there is an `onchanged` event to validate the first name and last name fields. But every time I enter something in the field, I get an error about the incorrect data entered. For example, I entered a word from 3 letters and received an error. … erased, wrote a valid switch to the last name input and receive a message “Wrong first name”. How can I fix this and how can I unify these two validation methods?

My js:

```
var namePattern = new RegExp("^([A-z]{4,20})$");
var fName = document.getElementById("fName").value;
var lName = document.getElementById("lName").value;
var checker = false

function validateFirstName(){
      if(!namePattern.test(fName)){
          checker = "Wrong first name";
      }
      if(checker){
          alert(checker);
      }
}

function validateLastName(){
    if(!namePattern.test(lName)){
       checker = "Wrong last name";
    }
    if(checker){
       alert(checker);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3>PERSONAL INFORMATION</h3>
<div>
    <span>First Name<label>*</label></span>
    <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName"
        placeholder="Your first name" onchange="validateFirstName()">
</div>
<div>
    <span>Last Name<label>*</label></span>
    <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName"
        placeholder="Your last name" onchange="validateLastName()">
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed some of the grammar, but there is a bit that I can not make sense of, can you fix “erased, wrote a valid switch to the last name input”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is that you don't take the current value of the field you're checking.

Second problem is that you don't reset the checker. Once you have an error the checker will have a truthy value until you refresh the page.

There are many ways to fix it.

My suggestion is this:

```js
var namePattern = new RegExp("^([A-z]{4,20})$");
var isValid = false;

function validateName(value, message){
    isValid = namePattern.test(value);
    if (!isValid) {
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

```html
<h3>PERSONAL INFORMATION</h3>
<div>
    <span>First Name<label>*</label></span>
    <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName"
        placeholder="Your first name" onchange="validateName(this.value, 'Wrong first name')">
</div>
<div>
    <span>Last Name<label>*</label></span>
    <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName"
        placeholder="Your last name" onchange="validateName(this.value, 'Wrong last name')">
</div>
```

This also combines your validation methods into one.

---

If you want to check all the fields are valid and not just the last field you edit, you'll need to have an `isValid` boolean for each of the fields and check they are all true.

Something like this:

```js
var namePattern = new RegExp("^([A-z]{4,20})$");
var isValid = {
  fName : false,
  lName : false,
};

function validateName(element, message){
    isValid[element.id] = namePattern.test(element.value);
    if (!isValid[element.id]) {
        alert(message);
    }
}

function isFormValid() {
  for (field in isValid) {
    if (!isValid[field]) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>PERSONAL INFORMATION</h3>
<div>
    <span>First Name<label>*</label></span>
    <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName"
        placeholder="Your first name" onchange="validateName(this, 'Wrong first name')">
</div>
<div>
    <span>Last Name<label>*</label></span>
    <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName"
        placeholder="Your last name" onchange="validateName(this, 'Wrong last name')">
</div>
<button onclick="alert(isFormValid())">Is Form Valid</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are collecting `fName` outside the function.So the fName will be set event befor the function executes which will be an empty string. So get the value of `fName` & `lName` inside the respective function

```js
var namePattern = new RegExp("^([A-z]{4,20})$");

function validateFirstName() {
  var fName = document.getElementById("fName").value;
  var checker = false
  if (!namePattern.test(fName)) {
    checker = true;
  }
  if (checker) {
    alert("Wrong first name");
  }
}

function validateLastName() {
  var lName = document.getElementById("lName").value;
  var checker = false
  if (!namePattern.test(lName)) {
    checker = true;
  }
  if (checker) {
    alert('Wrong last name');
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>PERSONAL INFORMATION</h3>
<div>
  <span>First Name<label>*</label></span>
  <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" placeholder="Your first name" onchange="validateFirstName()">
</div>
<div>
  <span>Last Name<label>*</label></span>
  <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" placeholder="Your last name" onchange="validateLastName()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is just a bit shorter code sample @VIRICH:

```js
var namePattern = new RegExp("^([A-z]{4,20})$");

function validateField(event) {
  var name = event.target.value;
  var checker = false

if (!namePattern.test(name)) {
    checker = true;
  }
  if (checker) {
    alert("Wrong value");
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>PERSONAL INFORMATION</h3>
<div>
  <span>First Name<label>*</label></span>
  <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" placeholder="Your first name"
  onchange="validateField(event);">
</div>
<div>
  <span>Last Name<label>*</label></span>
  <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" placeholder="Your last name"
  onchange="validateField(event);">
</div>
```